# Quadratic Casimir of Higher dimensional representations

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, invariants

I am trying to find the quadratic Casimir of a 45 dimensional representation of ${\rm SU}(5)$. However, in many references, the dimension of the representation of ${\rm SU}(N)$ are $N, N^2-1, N(N-1)/2, N(N+1)/2$.

Therefore, the possible dimensions of ${\rm SU}(5)$ are 5, 24, 10 and 15. I have the formulae to find the associated quadratic Casimir and Dynkin index of these representations.

However, how do I find the quadratic Casimir of the 45?

Answer (score 0):

(Quadratic) Casimir elements can be represented in terms of elements of the (universal enveloping algebra of the) associated Lie algebra.  For SU($n$) this Lie algebra is $\frak{su}(n)$.  This Lie algebra can be represented in terms of the generators of the group by

$$[T_a,T_b] = f_{ab}^{\;\;c}T_c$$

Then a (quadratic) Casimir $C$ is one for which

$$[T_a,C]=0$$

for all generators $T_a$.

It sounds like you know the structure constants $f_{ab}^{\;\;c}$ of your group of interest, and so if you can decompose your formulae for Casimirs in different representations in terms of the corresponding generators in each representation, you should find that they are the same, and that you can then immediately write down the Casimir for your representation of interest by reusing the same formula with the corresponding generators.

Answer (score 0):

You have not shown your work, so it is hard to tell how you are applying your formulae, and plugging in to get your answers.

The Dynkin indices (a,b,c,d) of an SU(5) irrep Λ give you the dimensionality
$$ N(a,b,c,d)  
=(1+a)(1+b)(1+c)(1+d)\\  \times  \left(1+\frac{a+b}{2}\right) \left(1+\frac{b+c}{2}\right) \left(1+\frac{c+d}{2}\right) \left(1+\frac{a+b+c}{3}\right)\left(1+\frac{b+c+d}{3}\right)\\  \times \left(1+\frac{a+b+c+d}{4}\right), $$
Hence
$$
N(1,0,0,0)=5 \\
N(0100)=10  \\
N(2000)=15  \\
N(1001)=24  \\
N(0003)=35  \\
N(0011)=40 \\
N(0101)=45  , ...$$
and so on, while their quadratic Casimirs are, in that order,
$$
24/5;~72/10;~24\cdot 7/15; ~~~10~~~;~24\cdot 28/35; ~ 24\cdot 22/40; \\
24\cdot 24/45  ~~~...
$$
the last line, 64/5,  being the Casimir of the **45**.

You may check by your hook rule that (0101) is indeed the antisymmetric traceless **45**, of course. (For *SU(N)* it would be the $N(N(N-1)/2-1)$-dimensional one.)  The Young tableau has a 4-story column and a 2-story one.

Comment: I understand the dimensionality formula. But how are you computing the quadratic Casimirs?

Comment: I am not computing them, I'm reading them up. [Slansky](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.126.1581&rep=rep1&type=pdf) and [Iachello's book](https://www.amazon.com/Algebras-Applications-Lecture-Notes-Physics-dp-3662444933/dp/3662444933/ref=dp_ob_title_bk) use different notations, but, of course, their formulas agree. I gather the OP is not asking about the *method* or algorithms, a deservedly longer story.

Comment: Thanks for the reference Cosmas. I haven't seen this Slansky before and it's very useful. Much appreciated

Comment: I think you have a typo. $N(0011)$ should be $40$, not $22$. $22$ is the index, not the dimensionality, for that irrep. The Casimir for that irrep has the right values.

Comment: Right, thanks, fixed it. You got the drift...